# Validate Images are loaded properly and visible on website using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen

Validation Scenario as follows :
During website check using URL response we get 200 OK as response. There are instances observed when due to some CSS file or JS file loading error we are not able to see images on website getting loaded.

I need to do validation in given scenario using Selenium and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
List<String> imageAlts = {"imageAlt1", "imageAlt2"};
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img");
for (WebElement image: images) {
    String imageAlt = image.getAttribute("alt");
    if (imageAlts.contains(imageAlt)) {
        int x = image.getLocation().getX();
        int y = image.getLocation().getY();
        int w = image.getRect().getWidth();
        int h = image.getRect().getHeight();
        if (x > 0 && y > 0 && w > 0 && h > 0) {
            System.out.println("image with alt " + imageAlt + " is visible");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("image with alt " + imageAlt + " is NOT visible");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("image with alt " + imageAlt + " NOT found");
    }
}
```

Comment: One question : Where can we mention image location i.e id or xpath or css of image ?

Comment: Getting `id` as any other attribute -> `element.getAttribute("id");` Getting css value is simillar -> `element.getCssValue("display")`.